# I want to apply unpivot function in SQL Server and Sqllite

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I have below table

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | WeekStartsOn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 2019-09-06 |

I want to convert it to below table

| DayOftheWeek | ActualHrs | WeekStartsOn | TimecardDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | 8 | 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-07 |
| Tuesday | 8 | 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-08 |
| Wednesday | 8 | 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-09 |
| Thursday | 8 | 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-10 |
| Friday | 8 | 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-11 |

The logic To add **TimecardDate **is
for Monday-->WeekstartsOn+1, Tuesday--> WeekStartsOn+2
....
, Friday--> WeekstartsOn+5

I have tried below Query

```sql
SELECT ActualHrs,DayOftheWeek,WeekStartsOn
FROM (select Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,WeekStartsOn
from itplanning.enriched.timecard_enriched_current) as cp 
UNPIVOT 
( 
ActualHrs FOR DayOftheWeek IN (Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday ) 
) 
AS PivotTable
where ActualHrs<>0
```

with this Above query, I have got below table

| DayOftheWeek | ActualHrs | WeekStartsOn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | 8 | 2019-09-06 |
| Tuesday | 8 | 2019-09-06 |
| Wednesday | 8 | 2019-09-06 |
| Thursday | 8 | 2019-09-06 |
| Friday | 8 | 2019-09-06 |

I am unable to do the **TimecardDate** column.

Actual table is below

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | WeekStartsOn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 2019-09-06 |

Expected Table is below

| DayOftheWeek | ActualHrs | WeekStartsOn | TimecardDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | 8 | 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-07 |
| Tuesday | 8 | 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-08 |
| Wednesday | 8 | 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-09 |
| Thursday | 8 | 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-10 |
| Friday | 8 | 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-11 |

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: please add your example data and expected.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this instead:

```sql
SELECT  v.d,v.hours,DATEADD(DAY, v.addDay, WeekStartsOn), WeekStartsOn
FROM itplanning.enriched.timecard_enriched_current
CROSS APPLY (
  VALUES(Monday,'Monday', 1),(Tuesday,'Tuesday', 2),(Wednesday, 'Wednesday', 3),(Thursday, 'Thursday', 4),(Friday, 'Friday', 5)
 ) v(hours, d, addDay)
where hours<>0
```

I unpivot manually and creates a two column table containing week and how many days to add to start of the week

Edit: added an alternative that does it with pivot syntax

```sql
select *
,   dateadd(day, case DayOftheWeek when 'monday' then 1 when 'tuesday' then 2 when 'wednesday' then 3 when 'thursday' then 4 when 'friday' then 5 end, weekstartson) AS TimecardDate
FROM itplanning.enriched.timecard_enriched_current
UNPIVOT 
( 
ActualHrs FOR DayOftheWeek IN (Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday ) 
) 
AS PivotTable
```

Edit #3 (SQLite edition):

```sql
with cte as (
    select monday, 'monday', 1 AS addition, weekstartson
    from timecard_enriched_current
    union
    select tuesday, 'tuesday', 2, weekstartson
    from timecard_enriched_current
    union
    select wednesday, 'wednesday', 3, weekstartson
    from timecard_enriched_current
    union
    select thursday, 'thursday', 4, weekstartson
    from timecard_enriched_current
    union
    select friday, 'friday', 5, weekstartson
    from timecard_enriched_current
    ) 
select *, DATE(weekstartson, '+' || addition || ' days') AS TimecardDate
from cte
order by addition
```

Comment: I have tried this query but it is showing " Invalid Column ActualHrs" but ActualHrs present in DB.

Comment: sorry, try this version :)

Comment: I'm trying this in Sqllite but it's not working. Is there any other function to do this?

Comment: added a version that uses unpivot, but not sure it works with sqllite

Comment: It is not working in sqllite

Comment: Ok, added another version :D

Comment: Well. That version does work for sql server of course. I don't think you can get same code that works in both because of the difference in syntax and functions